# Не происходит подключение к серверу Boost Asio

Tags: сеть, ip, boost, asio

Запустил сервер, взятого из примеров на сайте Boost::asio. К нему через localhost подключается, например в Chrome запросом http://127.0.0.1:1973/. Но никак не получается достучаться через Intenet, я просто узнаю ip и в Chrome запрос делаю http://176.213.0.10:1973/. Firewall в Windows 10 отключал.

Вот-так аксептор создается.

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), "1973");
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
        m_acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
        m_acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        m_acceptor.bind(endpoint);
        m_acceptor.listen();
```

Comment: А Вы уверенны, что у Вас внешний IP или порт правильно проброшен?

Comment: Не уверен. Как проверить?

Comment: запустить cmd и там выполнить ipconfig (под линуксом в терминале ifconfig) и посмотреть там какие айпи есть.

Comment: PPP adapter Broadband Connection:IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 100.77.109.159 Так тоже не проходит http://100.77.109.159:1973/

Comment: И почему различается ip на 2ip.ru и в консоле ipconfig?

Comment: 100.77.109.159 - это внутренний айпишник. То есть, "Вы за NAT'ом".   ip2.ru показывает внешний айпи Вашего (или провайдеровского) роутера. А по указанному выше айпи максимум сможет подключиться другой пользователь этого же провайдера (но не факт)

Comment: Так почему же я не могу подключиться к серверу? На этом же компе и подключаюсь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67640/discussion-between-tarakan-and-kovadim).